# How to read Image from a specific folder on Android 10 using MediaStore

Tags: android, kotlin, storage, mediastore, android-10.0

I'm trying to read Image from DCIM/Folder_Name(the location where the app saves image ).I need to display the image like a gallery only from that Folder_Name.
I tried using MediaStore with query and cursor .  But I come out only with bucket names which is the name of the folder containing images . I don't know how to filter only Folder_name and it's content inside . Here is my code.

```
val projection= arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_ID,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_ID)
val cursor: Cursor? = contentResolver.query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,projection,"",null,MediaStore.Images.Media.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER)
cursor?.moveToFirst()
if(cursor!=null){
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast){
        Log.d("CURSOr","Name "+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME)))
        cursor.moveToNext()
    }
}
cursor?.close()
```

How to use selection query in Android 10 for select desire folders content
Thank you .

Comment: If your folder is fixed and never going to change, you can skip MediaStore altogether. The only added benefit with MediaStore is that you can put a content observer.

Comment: `But I come out only with bucket names which is the name of the folder containing images .` Well is it "Folder_Name"? Then you are done. Otherwise tell what you get as all is pretty unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a projection on `RELATIVE_PATH` constant instead of `BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME` (which just gives you the name of last folder) and a selection of `LIKE DCIM/Test%` using the below code to filter out the results from `DCIM/Test` folder.

```
val projection = arrayOf(_ID, DATE_ADDED, BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME, RELATIVE_PATH)
val selection = "${MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH} LIKE ?"
val selectionArgs = arrayOf("DCIM/Test%") // Test was my folder name
val sortOrder = "$DATE_ADDED DESC"

app.contentResolver.query(
    EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
    projection,
    selection,
    selectionArgs,
    sortOrder
)?.use {
    val id = it.getColumnIndexOrThrow(_ID)
    val bucket = it.getColumnIndexOrThrow(BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME)
    val date = it.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DATE_ADDED)
    val path = it.getColumnIndexOrThrow(RELATIVE_PATH)
    while (it.moveToNext()) {
        // Iterate the cursor
    }
}
```

The only disadvantage of this approach is that `RELATIVE_PATH` is available for API level 29 (Q) and above.

**Edit:** Changed the selection args from `%DCIM/Test%` to `DCIM/Test%` as pointed out by [Alejandro Gomez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12746725/alejandro-gomez). The prior will match to any DCIM folder (including the system default) eg. `My/DCIM/Test/Sample.jpg` will also be in the output alongside `DCIM/Test/Sample.jpg`.

Comment: Your answer delivers ALL files with "%DCIM/Test%" is part of it. So You get files in /my/DCIM/TEST also as You get files in /DCIM/Test/privat/picx.

Comment: @AlejandroGomez So it a good thing or a bad thing?

Comment: i don't think that was the question. it was asking how to get files from one directory only.

Comment: @AlejandroGomez Oh I get your point. If someone has a duplicate, non-system folder called DCIM somewhere else, than the prefix % will match it and show the files. Thanks for pointing it out, I'll update the answer to remove the prefix %.

Comment: I think, that won't work, because that is, when paths are like "myImages/camera/DCIM/Test/"?

Comment: For the default DCIM folder, RELATIVE_PATH always starts as DCIM/... truncating the storage root folder. More info on RELATIVE_PATH here -- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns#RELATIVE_PATH

Comment: Bottomline is - if you know the prefix path from root of the storage, you need to write it down completely and then put a %, else you risk matching it to some unintended folder. If you've multiple folders to select, you can always provide multiple selection args.

Comment: What is the syntax for getting an exact image based on its display name from a specific folder using MediaStore ?

Comment: @KARUNESHPALEKAR You can change the `LIKE ?` to `== ?` in the `selection` to do an exact match. Make sure to update the `selectionArgs` with the exact value as well.

Comment: No it doesNot works . It returns null . I have passed the exact fileName thought and have checked it using Log . Further help is appreciated

Comment: Also I have the right RELATIVEPATH i have verified that too

Comment: @KARUNESHPALEKAR Can you post a question with the code? That will help me and others to try out the scenario and provide you with a solution.

Comment: I solved it . Since I was looking for the data based on fileName which i had stored in MEDIASTORE.IMAGE.MEDIA.DISPLAY_NAME . I had to use DISPLAYNAME in the selection arguement and retreive the data